# Rails - how to fix/convert incorrect string value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

I am facing this issue recently:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xCC\x81T LO...' for column
```

I found a lot of similar topics here on SO, but most of them are MySQL-related. Is there a universal way (method) to automatically remove "bad"/incorrect characters from the entered string, so I could save them to MySQL?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `encoding: utf8mb4 ` in database.yml http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: Sounds like you still have a non-utf-8 collation on this column in your table in the database. I was thinking that Stone Age is over.

Comment: I am currently using only `encoding: utf8` in the `database.yml`.

Comment: CC81 is "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" in utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Answer (score 4):

If this is issue with characters that require 4 bytes you need to use

```
encoding: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_bin
```

in database.yml

Comment: Thanks! I also has recreated my database with these parameters and it works!

Comment: Gediminas, I am glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Column, Database and Application has the same collation/encoding set.

1. **MySQL:** `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html`
2. **ActiveRecord:** `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation`
3. **Rails** `config.encoding sets up the application-wide encoding. Defaults to UTF-8.`

Also try playing around within the console `str.force_encoding("UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. edit your `database.yml` with below code line

`encoding: utf8`

Hope this will help.

Comment: I am currently using `encoding: utf8` in the `database.yml`.

Comment: ok, then try this 
`encoding: utf8mb4
 collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
make sure you restart the app after edit the `database.yml`

Comment: If it's not works try this one 
`encoding: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

RoR: `application_controller.rb`

```
  def configure_charsets
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES UTF8'
    end
  end
```